# AttributeError while Plotting GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, geopandas, plot, attributeerror

I am new to geopandas. I am trying to plot the locations of bays and gulfs. I have a csv file containing their names. After geocoding and finding their locations, I tried to plot the points on a world map.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from geopandas.tools import geocode
data=pd.read_csv("Bays and Gulfs of the World.csv")
def geocoder(row):
    try:
        point = geocode(row, provider='nominatim',user_agent="my_application").geometry.iloc[0]
        return pd.Series({'Latitude': point.y, 'Longitude': point.x, 'geometry': point})
    except:
        return None

data[['Latitude', 'Longitude', 'geometry']] = data.apply(lambda x: geocoder(x['Gulf/Bay']), axis=1)
map_bays_gulf=gpd.GeoDataFrame(data,geometry=data.geometry)
world_map= gpd.read_file("Worldshpfile")
world_map.crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
map_bays_gulf.crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
world_map.plot(ax=world_map)
map_bays_gulf.plot()
```

When I don't enter the `ax` parameter's value, everything goes fine. But after giving `ax`, the following error shows up. Can't figure out the reason.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-b8b5e5eee861> in <module>
      3 world_map.crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
      4 map_bays_gulf.crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
----> 5 world_map.plot(ax=world_map)
      6 map_bays_gulf.plot()


AttributeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'set_aspect'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a map with more than one layers as is your case (the base `worl_map` layer and the overlay `map_bays_gulf`) there are at least two posible options as it's explained in the [documentation of GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/docs/user_guide/mapping.html#maps-with-layers).

- Assign the output of the `plot` method to a variable and use it as the `ax` parameter of the second call to `plot`
- Create a `Axes` object calling [plt.subplots()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots), and using it as the `ax` parameter for both calls to `plot`

So this will work:

```py
base = world_map.plot(color='white', edgecolor='black')
map_bays_gulf.plot(ax=base, marker='o', color='red', markersize=5)
```

And this should also work:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect('equal')

world_map.plot(ax=ax, color='white', edgecolor='black')
map_bays_gulf.plot(ax=ax, marker='o', color='red', markersize=5)

plt.show();
```